# $PA=LU$ decomposition for the special matrix

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, lu-decomposition

The cost of decomposition $LU=PA$ for the matrix $A_{N\times N}$ is $O(N^3)$. However if we know about some special properties of matrix $A$ then we can reduce this cost but I wonder how to do it.

In my book it is written that for example for matrix A such that $a_{ij}=0$ for $i>j+1$ and $\det A\neq 0$ this cost can be $O(N^2)$ but 
I can't imagine an algorithm that would do that.

Can anyone present such an algorithm?

Comment: The same algorithm. Except that there are already many zeros, hence less computations: the LU decomposition using pivoting to make matrix entries below the diagonal vanish. What happens when they are almost all already null?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I get upper triangular matrix so I have $U$

Comment: Sure. It's the purpose of the algorithm. But, let's consider only the first pivot, and the first column of $A$. How much computations? By the way, such a matrix is called an [upper Hessenberg matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessenberg_matrix).

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut in the first column of $A$ I have only two non-zero elements : $a_{11},a_{21}$ so I want to $a_{21}=0$ so it is one computation

Comment: Well, it's a bit more (you still have to update the row), but you get the idea. Now try to write down the algorithm (it's almost identical to the usual one) and prove the number of operations is $O(N^2)$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I still don't quite understand what the first step should look like ...

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Can I have some more tips?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107421/discussion-between-jean-claude-arbaut-and-liam153).